# Right usage of ruby global variable $*

Tags: ruby

I was wondering the right usage for global variable `$*`.

If the program has `puts $*[0]` it works great. On the contrary, if I use it as follows:

```
   for i in 2..$*[0]
```

a bad value for range (`ArgumentError`) is throw. Any advise is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

That's because it has the wrong type. Try this:

```
for i in 2..$*[0].to_i
```

Comment: Great. I'm learning ruby. I thought it would be cast to the right type like perl.

Answer (score -1):

ehm why would u use it ? 
if i am correct you could do this:

```
$hello = "Hello world"
```

it will work fine. 
you can use it for example if you have something like this:

```
$hello = "hello world"
class test
   def putHello()
    puts $hello
   end
end
t = test.new
```

Comment: ohw I am sorry. I thought it was a question about the $ type and when to use it. my mistake